# using two ids for one onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple search bar with animation on open/close, but I want to have both of them in one header.php, one for desktop and one for mobile since I have a mobile toolbar and I want to show it there.
This my my html structure for mobile:

```html
<div class="mobile-toolbar">
    <div class="search-bar">
        <button class="btn-search-subxxmit" aria-label="Search submit" disabled type="submit"><i class="ti-search icon-search" id="icon-search"></i></button>
        <input type="text" class="search-field" id="search-field" value="" placeholder="Search by keyword">
        <span class="search-clear">╳</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I have on my desktop:

```html
<div class="header-toolbar">
    <div class="search-bar">
        <button class="btn-search-subxxmit" aria-label="Search submit" disabled type="submit"><i class="ti-search icon-search" id="icon-search"></i></button>
        <input type="text" class="search-field" id="search-field-desktop" value="" placeholder="Search by keyword">
        <span class="search-clear">╳</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
var mobTool = document.querySelector ( '.mobile-toolbar');
logo = mobTool.querySelector ( '.logo');
navBtn = mobTool.querySelector ('.mobile-nav-btn');
var bar = document.querySelector( '.search-bar' ),
icon = bar.querySelector( '.icon-search' ),
input = bar.querySelector( 'input' );
clear = bar.querySelector ( '.search-clear');
clear.style.opacity = '0';
icon.addEventListener( 'click' , function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //i can move this in a class
    icon.classList.add( 'clicked' );
    input.style.width = '50rem';
    input.style.padding = '0 35px';
    input.style.border = '1px solid gray';
    input.style.color = 'black';
    input.style.height = '60%';
    logo.style.display = 'none';
    navBtn.style.display = 'none';
    
    // clear.style.opacity = '1';
});
document.getElementById('search-field').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    if (e.target.value !== '') {
        clear.style.opacity = '1';
        clear.style.display = 'block';
    }
    // else {
    //     clear.style.opacity = '0';
    // }
});
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(function(){
        $('.search-clear').click(function(e){
            $('.search-field').val('');
            $('.search-clear').css('opacity','0');
        });
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var container = $(".search-bar");
        container.removeClass("clicked");
        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.removeClass("clicked");
            $('.search-field').css('width', '0');
            $('.search-field').css('padding', '0 0');
            $('.search-field').css('border', 'none');
            $('.search-clear').css('opacity','0');
            $('.mobile-toolbar .logo').css('display','inline-block');
            $('.mobile-toolbar .mobile-nav-btn').css('display','block');
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to edit this so I can use the same functionality on both mobile and desktop? I am using document.querySelector but I'm not sure if I should be using querySelectorAll, I'm new to this and I can't figure out how to do it. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: This does not answer the question, but instead of assigning all styling through JavaScript it's often easier to toggle a class. Then set the styling through CSS based on the toggled class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

1. Attach your event listener to both elements, using `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.search-input')].forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        // your code
    });
});
```

2. Take advantage of event bubbling - add the event listener to any common parent (I'm using the `<body>` below) and check if the element triggering the event is actually `.search-input`:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('search-input')) return;

    // your code
});
```

The second one has some advantages - you can add this code before the inputs are even in the DOM, and any new, dynamically added `.search-input` will also be handled by it.